# How to separate for loop from foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, foreach

```
   @foreach($cart_items as $cart_item)
 @for($i=1;$i<count($cart_items);$i++)

                <script>$(document).ready(function(c) {
                        $('.close{{$i}}').on('click', function(c){
                            $('.cart-header{{$i}}').fadeOut('slow', function(c){
                                $('.cart-header{{$i}}').remove();
                            });
                        });
                    });
                </script>




            <div class="cart-header{{$i}}">
               <div class="close{{$i}}"></div>
                    <div class="cart-sec simpleCart_shelfItem">
                        <div class="cart-item cyc">
                            <img src="{{asset(env('THEME'))}}/images/pic1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cart-item-info">
                            <h3><a href="#">{{$cart_item->name}}</a><span>Price: {{$cart_item->price}}</span></h3>
                            <ul class="qty">
                                <li><p>Qty : {{$cart_item->qty}}</p></li>
                                <li><p></p></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="delivery">
                                <p></p>
                                <span></span>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
 @endfor
 @endforeach
```

So, when I press close button, js removes div with item. I need to change class for every item in the list, but, because of foreach loop, for loop runs for amout of items in foreach loop. How can I run for loop only once?

Comment: Why is the foreach loop necessary when you are already looping over the cart items in a for loop?

Comment: Remove the for loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put @for cycle in `$(document).ready` or better rewrite the code - remove `@for`, remove `$i` from `.close` and `.cart-header` and in document-ready put:

```
$('.close').on('click', function() {
 $(this).children(".cart-header").fadeOut("slow").remove();
}
```

Comment: children didn't work, changed it to parent, it worked, but there's no more animation :(